# ListView scrolling Slow even using backThread to load images

Tags: android

My ImageCache

```
 public class ImageCache {
    private static ImageCache instance;
    private Context mContext;
    private HashMap<Chat, Boolean> isContain = new HashMap<Chat, Boolean>();
    private static Bitmap defaultBitmap;

    private int loginId;
    private WorkQueue workQueue;
    private LruCache<Chat, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<Chat, Bitmap>(
            (int) getMaxSize()) {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        protected int sizeOf(Chat key, Bitmap value) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
                return value.getByteCount();
            } else {
                return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();
            }
        }

        protected Bitmap create(Chat ChatKey) {
            if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
                Log.i("getView", "main thread");
                return null;
            }
            Log.i("getView", "image cache");
            // if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("main")){
            // return null;
            // }
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            if (ChatKey.getMsgType() == Chat.TYPE_IMAGE) {
                bitmap = getImageThumbnail(ChatKey);
                synchronized (isContain) {
                    isContain.put(ChatKey, true);
                }
                return bitmap;
            }
            bitmap = getVideoThumbnail(ChatKey);
            synchronized (isContain) {
                isContain.put(ChatKey, true);
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void entryRemoved(boolean evicted, Chat key, Bitmap oldValue,
                Bitmap newValue) {
            super.entryRemoved(evicted, key, oldValue, newValue);
            synchronized (isContain) {
                isContain.put(key, false);
            }
            oldValue.recycle();
            if (evicted) {
            }
        }
    };

    private Bitmap getVideoThumbnail(Chat chat) {
        if (chat.isPending()) {
            return getVideoThumbnail(chat.getFilePath());
        }
        if (loginId == chat.getSenderID()) {
            DataBaseHandler baseHandler = new DataBaseHandler(mContext);
            String fIlePath = baseHandler.getSentMsgFIlePath(chat.getMsgID());
            if (fIlePath != null) {
                return getVideoThumbnail(fIlePath);
            }
        }
        File file = new File(Util.videoDir, chat.getMsgID()
                + Util.getExtension(chat.getChatContent()));
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file = new File(Util.thumbnails, chat.getMsgID() + "");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                Util.downloadThumbnail(chat);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return getVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    private Bitmap getImageThumbnail(Chat chat) {
        if (chat.isPending()) {
            return getImageThumbnail(chat.getFilePath());
        }
        if (loginId == chat.getSenderID()) {

            DataBaseHandler baseHandler = new DataBaseHandler(mContext);
            String fIlePath = baseHandler.getSentMsgFIlePath(chat.getMsgID());
            if (fIlePath != null) {
                return getImageThumbnail(fIlePath);
            }
        }
        File file = new File(Util.imageDir, chat.getMsgID() + "");
        if (!file.exists()) {

            file = new File(Util.thumbnails, chat.getMsgID() + "");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                Util.downloadThumbnail(chat);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

            return image;
        }
        return getImageThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    private Bitmap getImageThumbnail(String imagePath) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        Bitmap image = null;
        if (imagePath == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID },
                new String(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + "=?"),
                new String[] { imagePath }, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            image = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    mContext.getContentResolver(), cursor.getInt(0),
                    Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
            cursor.close();
            return image;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }


    private Bitmap getVideoThumbnail(String imagePath) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID },
                new String(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + "=?"),
                new String[] { imagePath }, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            image = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    mContext.getContentResolver(), cursor.getInt(0),
                    Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            cursor.close();
            return image;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }

    private ImageCache(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        loginId = Util.getSharedPref(mContext).getInt(C.LOGIN_USER_ID, -1);
        defaultBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                R.drawable.image);
        workQueue = WorkQueue.getInstance(context);
    }

    public static ImageCache getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ImageCache(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private long getMaxSize() {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 4;
    }

    public boolean isBitmapLoaded(Chat key) {
        synchronized (isContain) {
            if (isContain.get(key) == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return isContain.get(key);
        }
    }

    public void getImage(Chat key){
        cache.get(key);
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmap(Chat key) {
        if (isBitmapLoaded(key)) {
            return cache.get(key);
        }
        workQueue.addRequest(key);
        return defaultBitmap;
    }

    public void remove(Chat key) {
        cache.remove(key);
        isContain.put(key, false);
    }

    public void evictAll() {
        cache.evictAll();
    }
  }
```

My workqueue

```
     public class WorkQueue {
    private final int MAX_THREAD = 1;
    private WorkerThread[] threads;
    private ArrayList<Chat> queue;
    private static WorkQueue instance;
    private ImageCache imageCache;
    private ImageLoadListner imageLoadListner;

    private WorkQueue(Context context) {
        threads = new WorkerThread[MAX_THREAD];

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) {
            threads[i] = new WorkerThread();
            threads[i].start();
        }
        queue = new ArrayList<Chat>();
    }

    public void setImageCache(ImageCache imageCache){
        this.imageCache=imageCache;
    }
    public static WorkQueue getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new WorkQueue(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addRequest(Chat key) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            if(queue.contains(key)){
                return;
            }
            if(queue.size()==20){
                queue.remove(0);
            }
            queue.add(key);
            queue.notify();
        }
    }

    public void setImageLoadListner(ImageLoadListner listner) {
        this.imageLoadListner = listner;
    }

    private class WorkerThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            setName("Background");
            synchronized (queue) {
                if (queue.size() == 0) {
                    try {
                        queue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            while (queue.size() > 0) {
                Chat chat = queue.get(0);
                imageCache.getImage(chat);
                imageLoadListner.onImageLoad(chat);
                synchronized (queue) {
                    queue.remove(0);
                    if (queue.size() == 0) {
                        try {
                            queue.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am calling getBitmap(key) from getView() of adapter and notify the adapter when an image load by calling the onIMageLoad() of adapter from workqueqe. Calling imagecache create from backthread even then LOg in create() of imageCache is printing and listView scrolling very slow due to the bitmap creating on backThread.

Comment: From the code above I see that background thread (WorkerThread) calls `getImage()` which just call LruCache `get` which in general doesn't load anything from filesystem or database. I think you could still load or decode images on UI thread. Turn strict mode and read logs. In addition extending `LruCache` definitely breaks KISS and S from SOLID rules

Comment: or, just don't waster your time with something that been done again n again by several very talented developers and just use a library that does it, for example my preferred http://square.github.io/picasso/ simple as `Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imgView);`

Answer (score 0):

Hanish U  should use LinkedList WorkQueue for`private ArrayList<Chat> queue;`  because in linked list addition or deletion is very  fast, and save the image id in Chat object because you are doing double work for fetching the Thumbnil  first get the Image id on path than get the thumb. 
and for Video u can use directly without changing your code

```
ThumbnailUtils.public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)
```

Comment: Thanx for your suggestions. I really found it helpful.